# does projected gradient descent with a convex cost function preserve monotonicity?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

If we have a convex function $f$, convex set C and define the projected gradient descent algorithm $x^{(t+1)}=Proj_C(x^{(t)}-\eta \nabla f(x^{(t)}))$ where the projection operator is defined as $Proj_{C}(x)=\mathop{\arg \min}\limits_{x_o \in C}||x-x_o||$, can $\eta$ be chosen small enough such that $f(x^{(t+1)})\le f(x^{(t)})$ for all t? So far I think this can only be shown if $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz, but I was wondering if it can be shown without this condition?

Comment: I think so, for definition of descent method. If the step size is too big, then it might not hold, but if small enough, it should hold. That's where the Lipschitzianity of the function comes to play, in the definition of the step size

Comment: See Corollary 28.10 of "Convex Analysis and Monotone Operator Theory in Hilbert Spaces" (2nd Edition).  It will outline all of the nitty-gritty details regarding the conditions under which the projection-gradient algorithm converges. The link is below:

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-48311-5